# How to use the emojis in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, encoding, emoji

I am working on doing the following :

a)  Implement  a  function enc ::  String -> String that  converts  all  lowercase  ASCII  letters into emojis and all uppercase ASCII letters into symbols representing animals.

b)  Implement a function dec ::  String -> String that implements the inverse function, converting emojis and symbols representing animals into ASCII letters.

I have started doing the following to check whether to decode or encode based on the input :

```
-- Peek into the content to decide whether we encode or decode.
convert :: String -> String
convert xs
 | null $ filter (\c -> isLetter c && isAscii c) xs = dec xs
 | otherwise = enc xs   

main = do
    contents <- getContents
    putStr $ convert contents
```

The problem is how to use the emojis in the haskell workflow. using emojis inside haskell always give me `parse input error` even when i am using `Data.Char`

Answer (score 1):

The question are not well-written, you're not explain where your problem is.

You can start from something like this

```
import Data.Char

toAnimal :: Char -> Char
toAnimal c = chr . (+127970) $ ord c

toSmileyEmoji :: Char-> Char
toSmileyEmoji c = chr . (+128415) $ ord c

encode :: String -> String
encode xs = map (\c -> if isUpper c then toAnimal c else toSmileyEmoji c) xs

fromAnimal :: Char -> Char
fromAnimal c = chr $ (ord c) - 127970

fromSmileyEmoji :: Char-> Char
fromSmileyEmoji c = chr $ (ord c) - 128415

isAnimal :: Char -> Bool
isAnimal c = if ((ord c >= ord '') && (ord c <= ord '')) then True else False

decode :: String -> String
decode xs = map (\c -> if isAnimal c then fromAnimal c else fromSmileyEmoji c) xs

main = do
    contents1 <- getLine
    contents2 <- getLine
    putStr $ (encode contents1) ++ "\n" ++ (decode contents2)
```

**Input**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**Output**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

https://ideone.com/iePD1a

Smiley emoji starts from 128512 and animal emoji starts from 128045 (Well, not the real actual 'start', but at least it can fit the alphabet letter). ASCII lowercase alphabet starts from 97 and 65 for the uppercase. You only have to add it so it will become the emoji you desire

e.g

```
65 [A] + (128045 [] - 65 [A]) = 128045 []
and so on...
```